# Search and replace string between tags

Tags: python, awk, sed, tr

I have the following document with 100,000 lines. In this document I have some translations in different languages, My problem is that I need to have "en_US" and "en" to be exactly the same (text between the  tags).
I trief using SED, AWK, TR but I´m not able to achieve my target and not affect other languages.
Any IDEAS?

```
  <prop type="context"></prop>
<tuv xml:lang="en_US">
    <seg>Enter and manage product details.</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="de">
    <seg>Geben Sie die Produkt-Details ein und verwalten Sie diese.</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="en">
    <seg>Enter and manage customer product details.</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="es">
    <seg>Introduzca y gestione los detalles del producto.</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="fr_FR">
    <seg>Entrez et gérez les détails sur le produit.</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="ja">
    <seg>商品の詳細を入力、管理します。</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="zh_CN">
    <seg>输入并管理产品详细信息。</seg>
</tuv>
```

Desired output:

```
      <prop type="context"></prop>
<tuv xml:lang="en_US">
    <seg>Enter and manage product details.</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="de">
    <seg>Geben Sie die Produkt-Details ein und verwalten Sie diese.</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="en">
    <seg>Enter and manage product details.</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="es">
    <seg>Introduzca y gestione los detalles del producto.</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="fr_FR">
    <seg>Entrez et gérez les détails sur le produit.</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="ja">
    <seg>商品の詳細を入力、管理します。</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="zh_CN">
    <seg>输入并管理产品详细信息。</seg>
</tuv>
```

Thank you!

Comment: :%s/"en"/"en_US"/g   in vim?

Comment: Thank You, What I need to change is the text between the "seg" tags:
<seg>Enter and manage customer product details.</seg> <-----

Comment: For that I think you need to rewrite the data in a new file with python.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment)

Comment: If `en_US` always preceeds `en` and `<seg` is one line only, then `sed '/"en_US"/{n;h};/"en"/{n;g}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does en_US always come first?

```
import sys
state = 'bypass'
for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.find("<tuv") >= 0 and line.find("en-US") >= 0:
        state = 'grab'
    elif line.find("<tuv") >= 0 and line.find("en") >= 0:
        state = 'replace'
    elif state == 'grab':
        grab = line
        state = 'bypass'
    elif state == 'replace':
        print(grab)
        state = 'bypass'
        continue
    print(line)
```

If this is more than a one-time thing, I might consider using an XML package to read the data, transform it, and write it back out, but this is fine for a one-off.

Comment: Nice. `elif state == 'grab'` and `elif state == 'replace'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awk solution

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{
  ins = "<seg>Enter and manage product details.</seg>"  # Store text to insert in variable ins
}
/<tuv xml:lang="en(_US)?">/{f=1}                        # When regexp is found, f is set
f{                                                      # With f true ...
  if(/<\/tuv>/) f=0                                     # if end tag is found, unset f 
  else sub(/<seg.*$/, ins)                              # else substitute <seg> with ins text
} 
{print}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input 
  <prop type="context"></prop>
<tuv xml:lang="en_US">
    <seg>Enter and manage product details.</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="de">
    <seg>Geben Sie die Produkt-Details ein und verwalten Sie diese.</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="en">
    <seg>Enter and manage product details.</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="es">
    <seg>Introduzca y gestione los detalles del producto.</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="fr_FR">
    <seg>Entrez et gérez les détails sur le produit.</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="ja">
    <seg>商品の詳細を入力、管理します。</seg>
</tuv>
<tuv xml:lang="zh_CN">
    <seg>输入并管理产品详细信息。</seg>
</tuv>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/"en_US"/{n;:a;N;/\n<\/tuv>/!ba;s/\n/\\n/gp}' file |
sed '1{x;s/^/cat -/e;x}
     /"en"/{n;:a;N;/\n<\/tuv>/!ba;g;s/\n.*//;s/\\n/\n/g;x;s/[^\n]*\n//;x}' file
```

Pick out lines following `en_US` and serialize (replace `\n` by `\\n`) up to the next `<\tuv>` tag and pass the result to stdout.

In a second piped invocation of sed, store the results from the previous sed invocation in the hold space.

Replace lines following `"en"` up to the tag `<\tuv>` with the paired serialized line from the first invocation.

Deserialize the lines and the remove that line from the hold space.

Repeat.

N.B. If `"en_US"`always preceeds `"en"` and the `seg` tag is only one line, use:

```
sed '/"en_US"/{n;h};/"en"/{n;g}' file
```